# How to plot a Gaussian function on Python?

Tags: python, plot, gaussian

I have a datafile like this

```
 Frequencies --    95.1444               208.5295               256.0966
 IR Inten    --     4.5950                 0.1425                 2.4807

 Frequencies --   273.7203               424.4748               446.9433
 IR Inten    --     0.6420                 0.0001                 0.9654

 Frequencies --   520.5846               561.6770               630.1851
 IR Inten    --     8.8996                 6.4944                 0.4674

 Frequencies --   703.7315               767.1711               799.2923
 IR Inten    --    23.7514                63.4507                15.9273
```

Each frequency is related with the IR intensity below, for example (frequency= 95.1444/ IR Inten= 4.5950), (frequency= 208,5295/ IR Inten= 0.1425).... And so on.

I have to construct on every frequency a gaussian curve with height the relative intensity of the strongest peak. The sum of all those curves should be a model of the IR-spectrum.

Here are some hints to do it:

A gaussian curve is:

```
import math
y = a*math.exp(-(x-b)**2/(2*c*c))
```

where

```
a: height of the peak
b: position of the center of the peak
c: controls the width of the peak
```

You can plot the function as follows:

```
import pylab
pylab.plot(xs,ys)  

# xs is a list of x-values
# ys is a list of y-values


pylab.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following library:
`import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to compute every x and y values, you can do it in this way computing mean and variance:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import math

mu = 0
variance = 1
sigma = math.sqrt(variance)
x = np.linspace(mu - 3*sigma, mu + 3*sigma, 100)
plt.plot(x,mlab.normpdf(x, mu, sigma))
plt.show()
```